# Automatic semicolon insertion: Alternate casting behavior on NodeJS vs Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, spidermonkey

I have noticed different behavior in NodeJS vs. Browser while screwing around with automatic semicolon insertion and type casting.

Browser:

```
> {}+{}
NaN
> {}+{};
NaN
> ({}+{})
"[object Object][object Object]"
> ({}+{});
"[object Object][object Object]"
```

NodeJS:

```
> {}+{}
'[object Object][object Object]'
> {}+{};
NaN
> ({}+{})
'[object Object][object Object]'
> ({}+{});
'[object Object][object Object]'
```

A. Why is casting interpreted differently with/without a semicolon or in parenthesis?

B. Which is more compliant to the standard? Or is this not addressed in the standard?

UPDATE: I found that it only does this different behavior in NodeJS. I previously thought this was V8 vs SpiderMonkey.

Comment: if you always use semicolons in your code, you don't need to worry about it =p

Comment: Well I do. I'm asking as more of a curiosity thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're entering this into different debug consoles.  One debug console treats that as a [*Program*](http://es5.github.io/#x14), and the other as an [*Expression*](http://es5.github.io/#x11).

---

> `{}+{}`

When interpreted as a *Program* this is equivalent to

```
{
  // empty block
}  // No semicolon inserted because statement is a block.
(+ Number({}))  // Prefix + operator coerces its argument to a number.
```

When interpreted as an *Expression* this is equivalent to

```
// Infix + operator concatenates if arguments are not both numeric
String({}) + String({});
```

which coerces each object to a string and concatenates those two strings.

---

> Which interpreter is more compliant to the standard? Or is this not addressed in the standard?

If, as I assume, this occurs in a debug console, then no standard addresses what a debug console has to do -- it can bypass the JavaScript interpreter entirely and interpret its input as COBOL.

If you pass it into `eval`, the first interpretation must win because the argument to `eval` is a string that is parsed as a *Program*.

Comment: Thank you! I had not considered this. Thanks for the quick response